# How to create and save subset dataframes for sequence of year-month

Tags: r, loops, date, subset

I would like to filter from a dataframe observations for a given year-month and then save it as a separate dataframe and name it with the respective year-month.

I would be grateful if someone could suggest a more efficient code than the one below. Also, this code is not filtering correctely the observations.

```
data <- data.frame(year  = c(rep(2012,12),rep(2013,12),rep(2014,12),rep(2015,12),rep(2016,12)),
                   month = rep(1:12,5),
                   info = seq(60)*100)
years <- 2012:2016
months <- 1:12
for(year in years){
  for(month in months){
    
    data_sel <- data %>%
      filter(year==year & month==month)
    
    if(month<10){
      month_alt <- paste0("0",month) # months 1-9 should show up as 01-09
    }
    
    Newname <- paste0(year,month_alt,'_','data_sel')
    assign(Newname, data_sel)
  }
}
```

The output I am looking to get is below (separate objects containing data from a given year-month):

```
> ls()
 [1] "201201_data_sel" "201202_data_sel" "201203_data_sel" "201204_data_sel"
 [5] "201205_data_sel" "201206_data_sel" "201207_data_sel" "201208_data_sel"
 [9] "201209_data_sel" "201301_data_sel" "201302_data_sel" "201303_data_sel"
[13] "201304_data_sel" "201305_data_sel" "201306_data_sel" "201307_data_sel"
[17] "201308_data_sel" "201309_data_sel" "201401_data_sel" "201402_data_sel"
[21] "201403_data_sel" "201404_data_sel" "201405_data_sel" "201406_data_sel"
[25] "201407_data_sel" "201408_data_sel" "201409_data_sel" "201501_data_sel"
[29] "201502_data_sel" "201503_data_sel" "201504_data_sel" "201505_data_sel"
[33] "201506_data_sel" "201507_data_sel" "201508_data_sel" "201509_data_sel"
[37] "201601_data_sel" "201602_data_sel" "201603_data_sel" "201604_data_sel"
[41] "201605_data_sel" "201606_data_sel" "201607_data_sel" "201608_data_sel"
[45] "201609_data_sel" "data"            "data_sel"        "month"          
[49] "month_alt"       "months"          "Newname"         "year"           
[53] "years"
```

Comment: Just a tip: `assign`, `for loops`, and naming `data`(conflicts with base function data) are almost never needed in R.

Comment: @NelsonGon Eh. `data` is a fine name for a generic dataset — name conflicts with base functions aren’t actually an issue (especially not for useless functions such as `data`, but also in general). The rest of your advice, I agree with. In particular, using `assign` here is a very bad idea. OP should use a (named) list for the results instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

g <- data %>% 
  mutate(month = sprintf("%02d", month)) %>% 
  group_by(year, month) 

setNames(group_split(g), with(group_keys(g), paste0("data_sel_", year, month))) %>% 
  list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Starting an object name with a digit is not allowed in `R`, so in `paste0` "data_sel_" is first.

As mentioned in the comments it might be better to *not* pipe to `list2env` and store the output as a list with named elements.

Comment: Removing the last expression would make this is a good solution.

Comment: @KonradRudolph do you mind elaborating? One draw back is that `list2env` will silently overwrite objects in the environment and this function can be slow, but are there other issues that are worth noting?

Comment: Well it’s just plain unnecessary in good code and it clutters your workspace environment with countless names. There’s no benefit to storing these results in separate variables, wanting to do so is a typical beginner mistake. Your edited answer covers this sufficiently, IMHO.